# Is this module a free $\mathbb{Z} $ module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

> Is $\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$ , where $n_i \in \mathbb{N} $ a free $\mathbb{Z} $
> module?

This question is from my modules assignment and I think I need help while attempting  this:

If it is a free $\mathbb{Z} $ module then there exists a basis set say { $x_1,..., x_n,... $} where each element is an infinite tuple.

Either I have to prove existence of such tuple or get some contradiction assuming that tuple exists.

Edit: I think $(1,0,0,...) , (0,1,0,0,...) , (0,0,1,0, \cdots),\cdots$ is such a basis and hence the module is free $\mathbb{Z}$ module. I took  all the entries of direct sum as $\mathbb{Z}$ mistakingly.

Attempt for $\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$'s : I think if I still define basis as (1,0,0,...) ,(0,1,0,0,0...),(0,0,1,0,0,...) this will still generate $\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$ but it will not be linearly independent as if it is Linearly independent then there exists $a_i$'s such that $(a_1,...,a_n,....)=(0,...,0,...)$ then $a_i's$ could be 0 mod $n_i'$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$. So, It is not Linearly independent.

So, is my proof  fine?

Comment: You got the right basis, but you should show that it actually is a basis.

Comment: By $\mathbf{Z}_{n_i}$ you mean the quotient group of $\mathbf{Z}$ by the subgroup generated by ${n_i}$? If this is the case, then this is a free module only if all ${n_i}$ are zero, because otherwise the module has torsion.

Comment: @Verca Ok! I have shown it.

Comment: @Jimmy I'm not sure what you've shown, but If I understood your question correctly, and as Andreas noted, this module is not a free $\mathbb{Z}$ module (in general).

Comment: @Rei I understand what mistake I was making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A free $\mathbb{Z}$-module cannot have torsion elements, that is, elements $x$ such that $mx=0$ for some integer $m\ne0$, because $\mathbb{Z}$ has no torsion element and a free module is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Your direct sum has torsion elements as soon as $n_i>0$ for some $i$.

It should be also noted that proving that the set you considered is not a basis doesn't prove that the module isn't free. For instance, $\mathbb{Z}$ is free and $\{2,3\}$ is a generating system that's not linearly independent. In other words, if you prove that some set is a basis, then the module is free; if you prove that some (generating) set is not a basis, you proved nothing.

Comment: Got it what mistake I was making. So, since the  $\oplus_{i=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}_{n_i}$ has torsional elements so it is not free. But , is this way of proving rigorious?

Comment: @Jimmy Why shouldn't it be? If an abelian group has torsion, it cannot be free, because free groups are torsion-free. However the converse is false in general, for instance $\mathbb{Q}$ is not free (because it is divisible and no nontrivial free group is divisible).

Comment: was thinking same but just wanted to confirm!